# NodeJS Express: How can I get my object to build completely before sending it in the response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build a `result_arr` of location objects to send as a response, but I am not sure how to send the response only when the entire array has been built. The response contains an empty array, but `result_arr` array is filled after the response has already been sent.

```
function handle_getLocations(req, res, done){
var con_id = req.body["contractor_id"];
console.log("Contractor ID :" + con_id.toString());
var result_arr = new Array();

employee.getActiveByContractor(con_id, function(err, employees){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Logging error in json:\n");
        res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
        return;
    };

    if(employees.length === 0) done(null);

    for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
        assignment.getLocationsByEmployeeID(employees[i].employee_id, function(err, locations){
            if (err) {
                console.log("Logging error in json:\n");
                res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
                return;
            };
            console.log("Number of locations: " + locations.length.toString());
            for(var j=0;j<locations.length;j++){
                console.log("Assignment is: " + locations[j].assignment_id.toString());
                location.getAllByID(locations[j].location_id, function(err, loc){
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Logging error in json:\n");
                        res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
                        return;
                    };

                    var loc_obj = {};
                    loc_obj.display_name = loc[0].display_name;
                    loc_obj.location_id = loc[0].location_id;
                    console.log("Location is: " + loc_obj.display_name);
                    console.log("Location ID is: " + loc_obj.location_id.toString());

                    result_arr.push(loc_obj);
                    console.log(result_arr);
                    done(result_arr);
                });
            };
        });
    };
});
```

};

I know that in nodejs the idea is to not make blocking calls, but I am not sure how to make sure all of the information is sent in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling many asynchronous functions in the loop and do not have any logic to check when all they are completed to send the response back to the client.

I modified your code a bit to add the logic in `VannilaJS` way which is very messy below but working code.

> Anyways I would suggest you to use promise based/asynchronous modules
>   like `async`, `bluebird` etc to handle this nicely. Using them, you
>   can improve readability and easy maintainability in your code to get
>   rid of `callback hells` and other disadvantages.

**async** http://caolan.github.io/async/

**bluebird** https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

You can read more about this on the below link,

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/

```
function handle_getLocations(req, res, done){
   var con_id = req.body["contractor_id"];
   console.log("Contractor ID :" + con_id.toString());
   var result_arr = new Array();

   employee.getActiveByContractor(con_id, function(err, employees){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Logging error in json:\n");
        res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
        return;
    };

    if(employees.length === 0) done(null);

    var employeesChecked = 0;
    var errors = [];

    function sendResponse(){
       if(employeesChecked === employees.length) {
       res.json(result_arr);
       //done(result_arr);  // If required, uncomment this line and comment the above line
      }
    }

    for(var i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
        assignment.getLocationsByEmployeeID(employees[i].employee_id, function(err, locations){
            var locationsChecked = 0;
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                errors.push(err);
                ++employeesChecked;

                sendResponse();
            } else {
            console.log("Number of locations: " + locations.length.toString());
            for(var j=0;j<locations.length;j++){
                console.log("Assignment is: " + locations[j].assignment_id.toString());
                location.getAllByID(locations[j].location_id, function(err, loc){
                    ++locationsChecked;
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        errors.push(err);
                    } else {
                    var loc_obj = {};
                    loc_obj.display_name = loc[0].display_name;
                    loc_obj.location_id = loc[0].location_id;
                    console.log("Location is: " + loc_obj.display_name);
                    console.log("Location ID is: " + loc_obj.location_id.toString());

                    result_arr.push(loc_obj);
                    console.log(result_arr);
                   }

                   if(locationsChecked === locations.length) {
                      ++employeesChecked;
                   }

                   sendResponse();
                });
            }
          }
        });
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Your tweaks instantly fixed the problem. I know the code is pretty ugly, but at least it works for testing. Thank you. Promises look like a good thing to invest some time in learning.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to consume much time during the **request-response** life time, you need to separate each logic in a single endpoint, but sometimes as your case, you may need to hit the database more than a time to fetch data that depends on another, so assuming that `employee.getActiveByContractor` returning promise and as it's an async method so you need to to chain it with `.then` like this:

```
 employee.getActiveByContractor(con_id)
        .then(function(employees) {
```

Also, you my need to read about [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As Basim says, this is a good time to use Promises.

`getLocationsByEmployeeID` and `getAllByID` are async so they won't be done by the time the loop is finished and you send your response.

Promises are built into the latest Node.js version.
Learn here: https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898

Suggestion:

1. Create promise wrappers for `getLocationsByEmployeeID` and `getAllByID`
2. Use Promise.all to make sure every `getLocationsByEmployeeID` and `getAllByID` are complete
3. return your http response within Promise.all's "success" callback